# Delay before first touch position changes on iPhone

Tags: iphone, touch, unity-game-engine

I have a problem using `Input.touches[0].position` on Unity3D. Sorry if the problem is unclear, I find it somewhat hard to describe.

When I start touching the screen and very slowly start to move my finger the position returned by `Input.touches[0].position` doesn't change immediatly, I have to move a little then it jumps to the current touch position.

This happens on iPhone, I don't have any other touch devices.

Here is some testable code illustrating it:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

// attach this to a game object on the scene
public class TestTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            // you have to add a GUIText component to the gameobject
            this.guiText.text = "pos: " + Input.touches[0].position;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just ignore the first delta, that is the first change in position, this solves my problem pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is cased by the early-gesture detection process.I'm not sure if it will solve your question but please try this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
{
    // Do sth.
}
```

Comment: Actually even if I ignore completely the touch phase, I still have the problem (I added code to my question to show this).

Answer (score 0):

If you need continuous touch positions, then use this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
   if(touches.count>0)
   {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
      NSLog("Touch position at (%4.2f|%4.2f)",touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it very clear, I'm actually using Unity3D, so the code is in C# with the Unity3D framework.